# Picasso for Android fails on some images

Tags: android, picasso

Picasso for Android works great but I'm having trouble loading some images.

The thing that causes issues is any resize or fit command. I'm using latest version of picasso.

Code example:

```
            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(url)
                        .fit()
                        .centerCrop()
                //.resize(Utility.pxFromDp(getActivity(), 100), Utility.pxFromDp(getActivity(), 100))
                .into(profile, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d("awesome", "picasso load woho");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Log.d("awesome", "picasso load error");// <-- this is called
                    }
                });
```

I've created an issue on github: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/933

Comment: "I'm having trouble loading some images" - what actually does it mean? app crashes?

Comment: @mklimek they don't load and call error callback

Comment: Debug the Picasso call. Try to find out what actually causes the error callback to be invoked. Without knowing what caused the error we cannot help you fix it.

Comment: @XaverKapeller should be easy to replicate, you got url and code, but yes  I could do that myself too :)

Comment: @Warpzit No, you should do that [turn debug on] before anything else, to see what is Picasso doing. Also, try using a hard-reference, non-anonymous callback just in case. If you post a question before debugging and finding out as much information as you can, you didn't do your homework :)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini I don't have much experience with picasso, I logged in logcat but it didn't print out anything of value (as far as I could tell) this is why I turned to stackoverflow. Also there were some issues on github with this issue, but they had all been closed, which again is why I thought it would be interesting to others eigther way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is generated by this method:

```
 public void reset(long token) throws IOException {
    if (offset > limit || token < reset) {
      throw new IOException("Cannot reset");
    }
    ...
  }
```

Because `offset` is greatest than `limit`. The limit is set in `decodeStream` method in `BitmapHunter` class. There you can find this line (117)

```
long mark = markStream.savePosition(65536); // TODO fix this crap.
```

I think that `TODO` comment is a answer for your question. This is issue from Piccasso library.

Comment: >_< haha that todo is really great. Well I'll have to make an issue about it on github then. Thanks for the help, You wouldn't happen to have an idea about how I could make a workaround?

Comment: This value is hardcoded also this API is not public. I don't have any idea how to resolve it but I am afraid that there is not right way to do this without some hacks.

Comment: Here is nice alternative for Piccasso https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Maybe it will be better for you

Comment: Also there is almost the same lib - Glade https://github.com/bumptech/glide